# The remaining check boxes to disappear when any four of is checked

Tags: java, android

I have this series of check boxes.. I want when any for is checked the remaining should disappear Have been trying to do this it has been giving me some head ache.. lately.. Please help me out if you can..

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="110.29"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:layout_weight="110.29" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbEng"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ENGLISH" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbMat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MATHEMATICS" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbPhy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PHYSICS" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbChe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CHEMISTRY" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbBio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BIOLOGY" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbGeo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GEOGRAPHY" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbAcc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FINANCIAL ACCOUNT" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbGov"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GOVERNMENT" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbEco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ECONOMICS" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCrk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CRK" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbLit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LITERARURE" />
      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Then In Java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class SubComb extends Activity {

TextView tvShow;
CheckBox Eng, Mat, Phy, Che, Bio, Geo, Acc, Gov, Eco, Crk, Lit;
int count = 0;
String[] Slot = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcomb);
    xmlConnect();



    Eng.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Eng";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;
                if (count == 3){Eng.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Mat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Phy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Che.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Bio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Geo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Acc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Gov.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Eco.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Crk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Lit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not                Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Mat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Mat";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Phy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Phy";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Che.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Che";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Bio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Bio";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Geo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Geo";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Acc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Acc";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Gov.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Gov";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Eco.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Eco";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Crk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Crk";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

    Lit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Slot[count] = "Lit";
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
                count++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count--;
                Slot[count] = null;
                String txCount = Integer.toString(count);
                tvShow.setText(txCount);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void xmlConnect() {
    tvShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
    Eng = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEng);
    Mat = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbMat);
    Phy = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbPhy);
    Che = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbChe);
    Bio = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbBio);
    Geo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbGeo);
    Acc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbAcc);
    Gov = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbGov);
    Eco = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEco);
    Crk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbCrk);
    Lit = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbLit);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you need fixed ScrollView? Its a better to use height of ScrollView to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener in your Activity and instead of setting different CheckChangedListeners, you can work this as

```
public class SubComb implements CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener {


 int count=0;
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if(b){

            count++;
            if(count==4){
                if(!Mat.isChecked()) Mat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Phy.isChecked()) Phy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Che.isChecked()) Che.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Bio.isChecked()) Bio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Geo.isChecked()) Geo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Acc.isChecked()) Acc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Gov.isChecked()) Gov.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Eco.isChecked()) Eco.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Crk.isChecked()) Crk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(!Lit.isChecked()) Lit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        else{
            count--;
        Mat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Phy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Che.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Bio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Geo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Acc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Gov.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Eco.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Crk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Lit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcomb);
    Eng = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEng);
    Mat = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbMat);
    Phy = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbPhy);
    Che = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbChe);
    Bio = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbBio);
    Geo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbGeo);
    Acc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbAcc);
    Gov = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbGov);
    Eco = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEco);
    Crk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbCrk);
    Lit = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbLit);


    Eng.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Mat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Phy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Che.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Bio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Geo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Acc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Gov.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Eco.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Crk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Lit.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: I Try doing that.. am having problem implementing OnCheckedChangeListener on check box .. Don't know whats wrong.. But it worked for Radio Grouped but not check boXes...

Comment: well I guess you might have imported Radio Group in your class and the IDE thinks that the CheckListener is of RadioGroup.

Comment: Try CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener or CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListner instead of just the OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Thanks ... I will Implement that now.. That must be where I was having problem I was only implementing OnCheckedChangeListener gonna get back as soon as possible to know how it goes Buddy

Comment: Have done that .. It work but.. am having problem getting the particular.. Check Box that is checked..??

Comment: You can get the id of the check box from compoundButton.getId() and use it in a switch statement

Comment: Thanks Buddy... I sent you message on facebook.. can you be my friend on facebook.. if you don't mind

Comment: I didn't get any message